# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over real numbers such that $AB=BA,$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was thinking about the following problem:

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over real numbers such that $AB=BA,$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $B$.Then which of the following options is correct?

> (a)$A$ must be zero,
>   (b)$A$ must be the identity,
>   (c)$A$ must be a diagonal matrix,
>   (d)$A$ must be either $0$ or the  identity.

I think the answer will be between $(c)$ and $(d)$. But i am not sure how to get the exact result.Can someone show me the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Others have answered this question, correctly, as (c). But be careful. It is not true that if $A$ is a diagonal matrix, it has this property. It is only true for a specific subset of diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Let $B$ be a diagonal matrix with pairwise disjoint diagonal entries. Then $AB=BA$ implies that $A$ is a diagonal matrix. This is very easy to prove, just write explicitly $AB$ and $BA$.

**P.S.** The most general thing you can prove about this problem is that $AB=BA$ for all $B$ if and only if $A= cI$.

Answer (score 6):

You can immediately rule out answers (a), (b) and (d) by considering the matrix $A = 2I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. This leaves (c) as the only option.

To actually prove statement (c), try looking at certain specific matrices $B$. For example, if $B$ is a matrix which has only one non-zero entry, what does the equation $AB=BA$ tell you about $A$?

Comment: thanks a lot .It is a very good approach for the multiple choice question like that.+1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Only (c) is correct. Just consider $n=2$ and $A=2I$. Then $AB=BA$ for all $2\times 2$ matrix $B$, but $A$ is neither zero nor identity.